# Array required, but List<Object> found

Tags: java

I am trying to get my new List I have created to go through the for loop as well as the int random I have created to randomize the items I have in my object list. the ***bank[i]*** as well as ***this.bank[random]*** is giving me the error "array required, but List  found". I am not sure how to do this with an object list. **Edit: I have fixed my main error but now my randomize function is out of bounds when I set the amount of questions I want to use**

## Bank Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestBank {

    public List<Object> bank;
    public TestBank() { // constructor
        this.bank = bank();
    }
    public static List<Object> bank() {
        List<Object> testBank = new ArrayList<>();
        String mcOne [] = {"Spongebob", "Fiore", "Patrick", "Sandy Cheeks"};
        String mcTwo [] = {"Canada", "China", "Russia", "United States"};
        String mcThree [] = {"California", "Pennsylvania", "Texas", "Alaska"};
        String mcFour [] = {"Washington, D.C.", "Boston", "Manhattan", "Philadelphia"};
        String mcFive [] = {"200", "206", "201", "205"};
        String mcSix [] = {"Shakespeare", "Stephen King", "Nathanial Hawthorne", "Ernest Hemingway"};
        String mcSeven [] = {"Jupiter", "Saturn", "Neptune", "Earth"};
        String mcEight [] = {"Van Gogh", "Da Vinci", "Picasso", "Monet"};

        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 1, 1, "How many points is a touchdown in American Football worth?", "6 points"));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 2, 1, "Which U.S. state is known for peaches?", "Georgia"));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 5, 1, "Name the longest river in the uk.", "River Severn"));
        testBank.add(new FillInTheBlankQuestion(5, 2, 1, "Temple Universities Mascot is __.", "An Owl", 6));
        testBank.add(new FillInTheBlankQuestion(20, 3, 1, "__ was the 16th US President.", "Abraham Lincoln", 15));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 1, 1, "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea?", "Spongebob", mcOne));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 4, 1, "What is the largest country in the world?", "Russia", mcTwo));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 4, 1, "What state is the largest state of the United States of America?", "Alaska", mcThree));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 2, 1, "In which city can you find the Liberty Bell?", "Philadelphia", mcFour));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 3, 1, "How many bones are there in the human body?", "206", mcFive));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 3, 1, "Who wrote The Scarlett Letter?", "Nathanial Hawthorne", mcSix));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 1, 1, "Which planet in our solar system is the largest?", "Jupiter", mcSeven));
        testBank.add(new MultipleChoiceQuestion(5, 2, 1, "Who painted the Mona Lisa?", "Da Vinci", mcEight));
        testBank.add(new FillInTheBlankQuestion(5, 1, 1, "The country that consumes the most chocolate is __", "Switzerland", 11));
        testBank.add(new FillInTheBlankQuestion(5, 2, 1, "__ is also known as Sodium Chloride", "Salt", 4));
        testBank.add(new FillInTheBlankQuestion(5, 2, 1, "__ is the Olympic sport that Michael Phelps is known for.", "Swimming", 8));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 2, 1, "Which astrological sign is a crab?", "Cancer"));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 4, 1, "How many boroughs are there in New York City?", "5"));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 5, 1, "What is the longest river in the world?", "Nile"));
        testBank.add(new ObjectiveQuestion(5, 1, 1, "How many days are in February during a leap year?", "29"));
        //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //newTest(in);
        //readFile(in);
        return testBank;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestBank test = new TestBank();
        test.newTest(in);
    }
    public void writeFile(String a, String b) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream bankFile = new PrintStream(new File(a + ".txt"));
        bankFile.print(b);
    }
    
    // makes new test files
    public boolean newTest(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{ // for NullPointerException error
        int amountQuestions = this.bank.size(); // amount of questions in bank
        //System.out.println(amountQuestions);
        int size = findLength(this.bank, in); // int for finding the length of questions to use
        //System.out.println(size);
        List<Object> bank = randomize(amountQuestions, size); // calls randomize function for size set
        Test newTest = new Test(bank);
        //String test = "-=-=-=-=-=-= [Questions] [Pts. " + newTest.getPoints() + "] =-=-=-=-=-=-\n\n" + newTest.toString();
        //String answers = "-=-=-=-=-=-= [Answers] [Pts. " + newTest.getPoints() + "] =-=-=-=-=-=-\n\n" + newTest.toAnswerString();
        String combined = "-=-=-=-=-=-= [Questions] [Pts. " + newTest.getPoints() + "] =-=-=-=-=-=-\n\n" + newTest.toString() + "-=-=-=-=-=-= [Answers] [Pts. " + newTest.getPoints() + "] =-=-=-=-=-=-\n\n" + newTest.toString();
        // System.out.print("Chose file name to store just new test questions -> ");
        // String name = fileName(in);
        // writeFile(name, test);
        // System.out.println("Making file for new test questions only...\n"); 
        
        // System.out.print("Chose file name to store just new answer key -> ");
        // String answerName = fileName(in);
        // writeFile(answerName, answers);
        // System.out.println("Making file for new test answer key only...\n"); 
        
        System.out.print("Chose file name to store questions and answers -> ");
        String qandA = in.next();
        writeFile(qandA, combined);
        System.out.println("(Making and outputting file for new test with questions and answer key...)\n");
        System.out.print(combined);
        return true; // returns true
        }
        catch (NullPointerException err) { // if it catches a NullPointerException error
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    // asks anount of questions to use and if it is over or above it asks again
    public int findLength(List<Object> bank, Scanner in) {
        int num = bank().size(); // int for length of bank
        System.out.print("Number of randomized questions? (5 pts. each) " + "(Up to " + num + " Questions) -> "); // asks how many questions out of the bank
        int size = in.nextInt(); // asks for an input of size to use
        
        while(size > num || size < 0) { // while not within length
            System.out.println("Not within range of questions, try again!"); // error
            System.out.println("How many questions do you want? " + "(Up to " + num + " Questions) -> "); // try again
            size = in.nextInt(); // calls scanner again to enter again
        }
        return size; // returns the size
    }
    // takes in amount of questions and size
    public List<Object> randomize(int amountQuestions, int size) {
        int usedQuestions[] = new int[amountQuestions]; // usedQuestions[] is amount of Q's
        ArrayList<Object> bank = new ArrayList<Object>(size); // bank is new ObjectiveQuestion of size entered
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for loop through size entered
            usedQuestions[i] = 1; // used question in idex is equal to 1
        }
    
        // randomize questions to array with no duplicates    
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for loop through size entered
            int random = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1)); // randomize 
            while(usedQuestions[random] == -1) { // while question is used and randomized
                random = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1)); // randomize 
            }
            bank.set(i, bank.get(random)); // each index of size in bank is equal to randomized bank
            usedQuestions[random] = -1; // usedQuestions is set to -1 so there are no duplicates
        }
        return bank; // return randomized array
    }
}
```

## Test.java code for the questions

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private List<Object> question;
    private int totalPoints;
    
    public Test(final List<Object> q) {
        question = q;
        for (Object a : question) {
            totalPoints += ((Question) a).getPoints();
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        String questions = "";
        for (Object a : question) {
                questions += a.toString();
        }
        return questions;
    }
    public String toAnswerKey() {
        String questions = "";
        for (Object a : question) {
            if(a instanceof ObjectiveQuestion || a instanceof FillInTheBlankQuestion || a instanceof MultipleChoiceQuestion) {
                questions += ((ObjectiveQuestion) a).toAnswerString();
            }
            else {
                questions += a.toString();
            }
        }
        return questions;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `bank`? can you post your full code please?

Comment: I have added my full code, bank is an Object List

Comment: You need to define a `Question` base class, make your questions subclasses of that, and make `List<Question> bank`.

Comment: I have a class for testing the questions with a list in it I can add that to the code

Answer (score 1):

`bank` is not an Array but a list. the index operator `[]` is reserved for arrays. For lists you need to use the `set(index, value)` and `get(index)` methods to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

is bank a list? if so try this:

```
 bank.set(i, bank.get(random));
```

Comment: It is now giving me an out of bounds error Index out of bounds for length 0 where I changed the value